# How to show UITableView inside UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I'm pushing detailViewController (UIViewController) from UITableViewController. detailViewController consists of UITextView and small UITableView. I have set my detailViewController to be UIViewController that implements UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols.I have delegate and datasource outlets in IB. I have those required table delegate and datasource methods that are called when detailViewController is pushed on top. I get called the methods that set number of sections (1) and number of rows in section (2). The problem is I do not see my tableView on screen when detailViewController is on top.

I have noticed that Xcode warns me about initWithStyle in detailViewController that it may not respond to [super initWithStyle:style]:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style{
  self = [super initWithStyle:style];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
  }
  return self;
}
```

I understand that it does not belong to UIViewController but how to get things worked out?

UPDATE: It appears my tableView is shrink-ed. I have set enough height and width for it in IB but it looks like the tableView appears on screen with very narrow one row and it does not resize when the tables fills with rows. IMHO it somehow related to being unable to call initWithStyle. Does anybody achieved similar solution in other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said, `detailViewController` is a `UIViewController` subclass. `UIViewController` does not implement `-initWithStyle:`, so the warning is legit.

Can't you subclass `detailViewController` from `UITableViewController`?

If you have to use `UIViewController`, you'd have to have `tableView` outlet created in `detailedViewController` and it should be connected to your table in IB. Did you make sure it's done?

Comment: Nop, I can't. I need to push detailViewController on navigationController stack. Only UIViewController might be pushed on top.

Comment: `UITableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, so you can push it on a navigation controller without a problem.

Comment: If I change parent class from UIViewController to UITableViewController in my detailViewController @interface declaration then program crashes on runtime when I push that detailViewController on navigation stack.

Comment: If you change only `@interface` declaration it will get out of sync with the `.xib` file and that might be the cause of a crash. Anyway, `UITableViewController` might be something you want to avoid anyway, since it's quite restrictive about adding other user interface elements than the table view. You'd have to place your text edit in header or footer view of the table.

Comment: Help, I am in exactly similar situation but I do not create any .xib. I create the tableView in [init] and push the view in viewDidLoad, but it still doesn't appear... :|